# Submit an ajax/jquery form without refreshing - INPUT = #msg, OUTPUT = #messages

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, chat

I basically have a form that you input chat messages into. It looks like chat roulette/omegle. You see yourself as YOU, and the other person as STRANGER. **I need to be able to reload the messages without refreshing the page when submitted.** This is at the bottom of the HTML page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var refreshchat = function(){
    $.get('ajax.php', function(data) {
        $('#messages').html(data);
    });
    var msgs = document.getElementById('messages');
    msgs.scrollTop = msgs.scrollHeight;
}
var getmsgs = self.setInterval(refreshchat,0);
$('#send').click(function(){
    var msg = $('#msg').val();
    $.post("ajax.php", { msg: msg, from: "You" },
       function(data) {
            $('#messages').html(data);
            $('#msg').val('');
            var msgs = document.getElementById('messages');
            msgs.scrollTop = msgs.scrollHeight;
    });
});
});

</script>
```

I saw [this question/answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897351/how-do-i-automatically-submit-this-form-without-refreshing-the-page), but am not sure how to make it work with this setup.

Comment: So whats the problem? What exactly don`t you know how to setup? jQuery, AJAX call, HTML elements or something else?

Comment: The little snippet of code they give to have it refresh.

Comment: if data is the list of messages, the code seems right. have you tried using a non-zero value for the setInterval, something as 500?

Comment: @Jessica, Are you familiar with JavaScript and PHP?

Comment: Someone built me the starter code for this and told me to add whatever I needed myself. I don't grasp javascript too well.

Comment: Yes I have, the problem is that when I hit SUBMIT, the page reloads. I don't want it to  reload.

Comment: I am not too familiar with PHP, but I figured how to clear the messages table earlier. I've only used it with WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the send button. *Edited: getmsgs is automatically called*. Other than the button, the only thing I can think of is the ajax.php file. Is that created?

```
 <input type="button" id="send">
```

Comment: '$('#send').click(function(){
  var msg = $('#msg').val();
  $.post("ajax.php", { msg: msg, from: "You" },
     function(data) {
    $('#messages').html(data);
    $('#msg').val('');
    var msgs = document.getElementById('messages');
    msgs.scrollTop = msgs.scrollHeight;'

Comment: As long as all your form inputs have the appropriate ids, I think that button is all you need. It might help to see the source.

Comment: Can I e-mail you it? jessicalares@gmail.com I don't want to have to copy and paste the whole thing here. Thanks.

Comment: Going by your comments above, it sounds like your only issue is that It's refreshing. Replace the type="submit" with type="button". Since It's all handled with javascript, it shouldn't have to submit.